# Is it a legal requirement to display company registration details?

Tags: legal

Is it a legal requirement to display company registration details (Office, country and reg no etc) on a UK Based corporate website?

I know that E-Commerce websites do, under the distance selling regulations, however the site I'm working on is not e-commerce, just a corporate website.

Comment: Why would you want to hide this information?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is a legal requirement to display company registration details on a UK based website. It's also good practise - it'll will reassure the company's customers that it's a serious organisation.

[Out-Law](http://www.out-law.com/page-431) site contains the relevant information.

> The name, geographic address and email address of the service provider. The name of the organisation with which the customer is contracting must be given.  This might differ from the trading name. Any such difference should be explained – e.g. "XYZ.com is the trading name of XYZ Enterprises Limited."

And according to [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/12/21/new_web_email_regulation/) from January 2007:

> Every company should list its company registration number, place of registration, and registered office address on its website as a result of an update to the legislation of 1985. The information, which must be in legible characters, should also appear on order forms and in emails.

This is part of the Companies Act and failure to do so will result in a fine.

Comment: +1 though small suggestion: The Out-Law article was updated much more recently than the Register piece. I'd rearranged this to reflect. No point in making people work through older information to get at it.

Comment: @Su' - The Register was the first result I found :)

Comment: Yes i found those articles too - it seems i must - Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Companies House (the regulator for UK companies) has a FAQ page about [trading disclosures](http://www.companieshouse.gov.uk/infoAndGuide/faq/tradingDisclosures.shtml) on its website, which says:

> Q. What do I need to display in my business letters, orders and
>   websites?
>
> A. The company name, number, place of registration, and its registered
>   office address.

(Company name is the registered name, though you can say that "[X] is a trading name of [Y] Limited", etc.)

This requirement is a result of the [Companies Act 2006](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/46/contents).